# How to set different [pageSize] in mat-paginator for different responsive resolutions

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-pagination

I want to avoid a vertical scroll bar in mat-table in the responsive resolutions. For that I need to reduce the mat-paginator [pageSize] attribute value to 4. Can we set different [pageSize] values for different resolutions?

```
<mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                          (page)="tableService.mgOnPaginateChange($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/height

Comment: You can take help of (CDK)[https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview] for this. Here is one directive built using CDK https://csharpcode.org/blog/detect-viewport-size-with-the-help-of-angular-cdk-breakpointobserver/